# osm сервер для использования в arcgis

Tags: gis, openstreetmap

Имеется развёрнутый osm tile сервер в локальной сети. Требуется подключить его в качестве базовой карты в arcgis. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcGis не имеет прямой поддержки tiled данных. Такая функция есть исключительно в веб версии arcgis online. Поэтому для схожего функционала был выбран wms сервер mapproxy для кэширования osm.